# challenging quoting issue in R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I need a function that produces a specific cross tab, using dplyr code style.

I have the following dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  g1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
  g2 = rep(c("a", "b"), 10),
  g3 = rep(c("w", "x", "y", "z"), 5),
  g4 = c("p", "p", "p", "p", "q", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "q", "q", "q", "q", "q", "p", "p", "p", "p", "q"),
  s = c(14, 21, 221, 132, 159, 22, 682, 23, 42, 256, 240, 202, 30, 31, 358, 34, 399, 347, 43, 63)
)
```

And I get the results I need in my global environment with the following piece of code:

```
df %>%
  group_by(g1, g2, g3, g4) %>%
  summarise(
    n_z = n(),
    sum_z = sum(s)
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(g1, g3),
    names_from = c(g2, g4), 
    values_from = c(n_z, sum_z)
  )
```

What I need is to functionize all of this, or something like:

```
fneeded <- function(df, row_zz, col_zz, stat_var, fs) {
  ?!
}

# the following function call should produce the requested results
df %>% 
   fneeded(
     row_zz = c(g1, g3), 
     col_zz = c(g2, g4), 
     stat_var = s, 
     fs = c(n, sum)
   )
```

And the function call should produce the same results as the second block of code above. Note that the arguments in the summarize should come from the fs argmuent of the function. If I pass 3 functions, there should be 3 line of codes there and later in the pivot 3 variables in values_from.

Could you please help? And let me know if I am not being explicit enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make use of `group_by_at` if we are passing a vector of strings in 'row_zz' and 'col_zz'

```
fneeded <- function(df, row_zz, col_zz, statVar) {
                      df %>%
                        group_by_at(c(row_zz, col_zz)) %>%
                        summarise(
                          n_z = n(),
                          sum_z = sum({{statVar}})
                        ) %>%
                        pivot_wider(
                          id_cols = row_zz,
                          names_from = col_zz, 
                          values_from = c(n_z, sum_z)
                        )

                      }

fneeded(df, row_zz = c('g1', 'g3'), col_zz = c('g2', 'g4'), statVar = s)
```

Comment: this does not deal with the quoting issues, it throws an error when I do the proposed function call for example you need enquo(row_zz) to be able to use it in a function like so

Comment: @criticalth  What is `s = c(n, sum)`  Are you calling `n()` with `n`

Comment: good question! that is a vector of functions! I have made edits in the task! It is a difficult task, do not underestimate. I have been trying to solve it for the past couple of hours!

Comment: @criticalth  The above function I showed works for me without the `fs` as I was not sure

Comment: to me it says " Error in (function (x)  : object 's' not found "

Comment: Sorry a typo, i used the wrong argument in `sum{{` it should work now

Comment: upvoting, your solution is useful, can we try to think of something about that fs argument?

Comment: @criticalth  The issue is with `n()` as you are passing `n`

Comment: thank you for answering, let's say that we do not need the count, let us say we need the sum and the max so that fs=c(sum, max) which should be accounted in the summarize(sum_z = sum(statVar), max_z = max(statVar)), and then the pivoting should use those two in the argument values_from.

Comment: You can use `length`

Comment: if we do it with one function, I would still be ok, I will be mapping and reducing with left_join through the rest, it would be fine. I think this simplifies the problem a lot.

Comment: sorry, busy, will check on it

Answer (score 1):

So I got somewhat of a solution using this:

```
fneeded <- function(df, row_zz, col_zz, fs, statVar) {

  fs_eval <- eval(parse(text = fs))

  df %>%
    group_by_at(c(row_zz, col_zz)) %>%
    summarise(
      !!fs := fs_eval({{statVar}})
    ) %>%
    pivot_wider(
      id_cols = row_zz,
      names_from = col_zz, 
      values_from = c(!!fs)
    )

}

fneeded(df, row_zz = c('g1', 'g3'), col_zz = c('g2', 'g4'), "mean", statVar = s)
```

I am accepting akrun's solution since it prompted to this code, even though this is a simplification sicne it takes only one function, it is easily extendable when purrring.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to pass additional functions as ... parameters.

Something like:

```
fneeded <- function(df, row_zz, col_zz, ...) {
  row_zz_sym = syms(row_zz)
  col_zz_sym = syms(col_zz)
  summaryvars = enquos(...)


  df <- df %>%
    group_by(!!!row_zz_sym, !!!col_zz_sym) %>%
    summarize(
      n_z = eval(summaryvars[[1]]),
      sum_z = eval(summaryvars[[2]])
    ) %>%
    pivot_wider(
      id_cols = row_zz,
      names_from = col_zz,
      values_from = c(n_z, sum_z)
    )

  return(df)
}

df %>% 
  fneeded(
    row_zz = c("g1", "g3"), 
    col_zz = c("g2", "g4"),
    n(),
    sum(s)
  )


# A tibble: 12 x 10
# Groups:   g1, g3 [12]
      g1 g3    n_z_a_p n_z_a_q n_z_b_p n_z_b_q sum_z_a_p sum_z_a_q sum_z_b_p sum_z_b_q
   <dbl> <fct>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1     1 w           1       1      NA      NA        14       159        NA        NA
 2     1 x          NA      NA       1      NA        NA        NA        21        NA
 3     1 y           1      NA      NA      NA       221        NA        NA        NA
 4     1 z          NA      NA       1      NA        NA        NA       132        NA
 5     2 w           1      NA      NA      NA        42        NA        NA        NA
 6     2 x          NA      NA       2      NA        NA        NA       278        NA
 7     2 y           1       1      NA      NA       682       240        NA        NA
 8     2 z          NA      NA       1       1        NA        NA        23       202
 9     3 w           1       1      NA      NA       399        30        NA        NA
10     3 x          NA      NA       1       1        NA        NA       347        31
11     3 y           1       1      NA      NA        43       358        NA        NA
12     3 z          NA      NA       1       1        NA        NA        34        63
```

The function first converts the collection of grouping variables to symbols, and enquotes the additional, unnamed parameters (the functions you want to use).
The grouping variables are spliced, and the quoted functions are evaluated for use in the summarize call.

I'm new to tidyevaluation, so this may not be the proper way of doing this, or it may not extend to `n` parameters, but I hope it helps for what you need.

Comment: that is interesting, how do you then make the "values_from" argument in the pivot self adjustable, for example if you pass three functions the pivot needs to take all three variables created in the summarize in the values_from arg? And also in the summarize you take only 2 functions, I need this to change on its own..